# Implementation on HTTP Only/Secure cookie in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies

Im trying to set http only cookie in Angular17:

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
async login(formObject: any) {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`${this.url}`, formObject);
      if (res.status !== 200) return;
      this.token = res.data.token;
      this.cookieService.set(
        'authToken', // Customize cookie name
        this.token,
        {
          expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600 * 1000),
          path: '/',
          domain: window.location.hostname,
          secure: true,
        },
      );
      console.log('http cookie set!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

but i am still able to see the cookie in dev tools.
This library has only a secure flag, but it doesnt work as well as http only cookie.
How to set Http Only Cookie in Angular?